# Clojure compare sequence to vector

Tags: vector, clojure, comparison, sequence

http://www.4clojure.com/problem/23: "Write a function which reverses a sequence"

One solution is `(fn [x] (reduce conj () x))`, which passes all the tests. However, I'm curious why that solution works for the first test:

```
(= (__ [1 2 3 4 5]) [5 4 3 2 1])
```

Inlining the function evaluates to `true` in the REPL:

```
(= ((fn [x] (reduce conj () x)) [1 2 3 4 5]) [5 4 3 2 1])
true
```

However, if I evaluate the first argument to the `=`, I get `(5 4 3 2 1)`, and `(= (5 4 3 2 1) [5 4 3 2 1])` throws a `ClassCastException`.

Why does the former work while the latter doesn't? It seems like they should be equivalent …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your list literal `(5 4 3 2 1)` is being evaluated as a function call. To use it properly you need to quote it, like so:

`(= '(5 4 3 2 1) [5 4 3 2 1]) ;; => true`

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it without reduce is to use `into ()`
as it works exatcly as your reduction. So when you fill the blank this way, it solves the task:

```
(= (into () [1 2 3 4 5]) [5 4 3 2 1]) ;; true
(= (into () (sorted-set 5 7 2 7)) '(7 5 2)) ;; true
(= (into () [[1 2][3 4][5 6]]) [[5 6][3 4][1 2]]) ;; true
```

Comment: Nice! Just getting started with Clojure, so I didn't know about `into`